# Which of these is the more portable way to set the maximum value of an unsigned integer?

Tags: c, casting, c99

In C99 compliant C, assuming no preprocessor macro defines, which is the more portable way of setting the maximum value of an unsigned integer:

```
unsigned x = -1;
```

or

```
unsigned y = ~0;
```

I recall a few years ago I came across a thread which claimed that setting the **unsigned int** to `-1` was more portable due to `~0` having some sort of *trap representation* on obscure systems; I no longer feel certain that is true though.

I know the behavior of setting a negative value to an unsigned variable is well defined in the C99 standard (i.e. modulo value, etc), but what about the inversion of `0`?

Furthermore, if both operations are equally portable, and assuming there is no compiler optimization, which operation would be more efficient in terms of clock cycles?

Comment: Both have the same performance: it is an assignement of constant value to some register. Both `-1` and `~0` values/expressions will be precomputed by the compiler and both should end up being a single MOV/LD/etc instruction, of course depending on the architecture..

Comment: For the inverted zero case, wouldn't a non-optimizing compiler first MOV `0` into a register, then execute an inversion operation, before another MOV instruction to save the value?

Comment: @VilhelmGray Then you could also consider that the compiler would move 1 to a register, negate it, add `UINT_MAX + 1` to it, and then moves the value to `x` for the first. If you allow for arbitrarily braindead compilers, you can't say much. On every half-reasonable compiler, both will produce the same code on two's complement machines, and have different results on ones' complement or sign-and-magnitude machines.

Comment: I understand your doubt, but I find it hard to believe that such obvious thing would not be "squashed" to a value. But, truly-nonoptimizing compiler would indeed probably do that. Anyways, the Daniel's note is more important here: ~0 is not always equal to -1, and I think you are more likely to find non-one-complement architecture than non-optimizing compiler.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I was tempted to say the same about "-1" as "-" and "1", but in fact, IIRC, the C standard defines numeric-literals to be signed, so "-1" is one numeric token, not an operator and value :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl The standard says (6.4.4.1 (2)): "An integer constant begins with a digit, but has no period or exponent part.", the minus sign is not part of an integer constant. `-1` is the unary minus operator applied to the integer constant 1. The type of a decimal integer constant (without suffix) is signed, but the value of an integer constant is non-negative.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Wow. Now I'm devastated. This is a real surprise. So there's no way of specifying a direct negative literal? I've to check C++ standard as that's my weapon of choice, but the more I think about it, it makes sense. At very specific machines and assemblers a signed MOV instruction may actually might not exist and may have to be emulated/calculated, especially if they were to modify some flags.. geesh. That's some reason for sure, but I'd never suspect it at integers. Thank you very much for digging that piece!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unsigned x = UINT_MAX;` works (after including `<limits.h>`), by definition of `UINT_MAX`.

`unsigned x = -1;` works by definition of how operations work with unsigned integers (`UINT_MAX+1` is added or subtracted to make the result representable, so `-1` becomes `-1+UINT_MAX+1` which equals `UINT_MAX`).

`unsigned x = ~0;` is not guaranteed to work, because `~` is defined as an operation on the bits of an integer, rather than an operation on the numeric value, but the bits of signed integers are not fully specified by the C standard.

`unsigned x = ~0u;` works, because `0u` is an unsigned integer, and its value bits are fully specified by the C standard.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned x = UINT_MAX;
```

Comment: I'm asking for a pure C answer (i.e. no preprocessor macros).

Comment: @VilhelmGray The preprocessor is a part of the C language, so it's as pure as it can be.

Comment: Forgive me, I see what you mean; I suppose I should have stated "without the standard C library."

Answer (score 3):

The first,

```
unsigned x = -1;
```

is more portable. It is guaranteed to set the value of `x` to `UINT_MAX` on every conforming implementation.

The second,

```
unsigned x = ~0;
```

does the bitwise complement on an `int`, so it is not guaranteed that the value of `~0` is `-1` - it isn't on ones' complement or sign-and-magnitude machines, and it even may be a trap representation.

The alternative

```
unsigned x = ~0u;
```

that takes the complement of an `unsigned` zero, is fully portable too.